# Simple Python error exercise

Tags: python

I have a very basic assignment, but I just simply can not get the right error I am looking for. Here is the assignment:

> 10-6 Addition: One common problem when prompting for numerical input occurs when people provide text instead of numbers. When you try to convert the input to an int, you'll get a TypeError. Write a program that that prompts for two numbers. Add them together and print the result. Catch the TypeError if either input value is not a number, and print a friendly error message. Test your program by entering two numbers and then by entering some text instead of a number.

Here is what I have:

```
print("Please enter two numbers and this program will add them together!")
try:
    num_1 = int(input("What is your first number?"))
    num_2 = int(input("What is your second number?"))
    answer = num_1 + num_2
    print(str(num_1) + " + " + str(num_2) + " = " + str(answer))
except TypeError:
    print("Please make sure you enter a number next time.")
```

I have rearranged this for like an hour now, and no matter what I do I can't get a TypeError, only a ValueError. How am I able to get a TypeError in this, or is the book just wrong and it is impossible to get a TypeError in this scenario??

Comment: I thought it was a `ValueError` if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> int('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

The book is wrong.

Comment: the book isn't wrong if it's been written when python 2 still used `input`. The OP wrote the code.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Python 2's `input` won't raise a `TypeError` for any non-contrived input I can think of, and it would also make the `int` redundant. And it says "When you try to convert the input to an int, you'll get a TypeError".

Comment: oooooh, the book is wrong, you're right. And the example is pointless...

Answer (score 0):

A TypeError is thrown when trying something like

```
answer = 2 + '3'
```

Your exercise is a bit misleading, because such a situation will never happen in a program like the one you are supposed to write. The error you can get when trying to explicitly convert a `str` to a `int` is a ValueError, as you say. So yes, catch the ValueError with

```
except ValueError:
```

and you are good to go.

Also, you are converting your `int` back into a `str` with the line

```
answer = num_1 + str(num_2)
```

which is incorrect. You should just do

```
answer = num_1 + num_2
```

Comment: it happens all the time in the code above if valid numbers are entered.

Comment: It should not happen if you change your code according to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The book is not wrong. The question didn't actually ask you to convert to `int`.

Just change to `num_1 = input("What is your first number?")` and `num_2` likewise and your exception handling will be triggered if exactly one of the inputs is a string.

Granted, it's a little confusing because of the line "When you try to convert the input to int, [...]" but nowhere did it ask you to do this conversion explicitly. It was probably just referring to the implicit conversion happening when using `+` with an integer and a string.

To learn a little more about Python, you could also test what happens if both inputs are a string.